# constant rendering of graphics vb.net

Tags: vb.net, performance, graphics

I am developing the GUI aspect of a program, it needs to be able to drag a line from one button to another.

I am also developing some path finding as I want these lines to be always visible  and child forms may be in the way if I draw a line directly from one button to another, therefor a single connection may be a lot more than 1 line drawn.

My question is. If I have 1000 lines drawn via e.graphics in a panel, which is redrawn every time I scroll or every time I hover the mouse over a button, triggering the paint event. Will so many lines have the potential to slow down the application?

Would putting the rendering of these lines on a different thread solve all issues?

Are there alternatives to using the graphics class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Potentially, yes. The only way to know is to try. You can't draw from a different thread. One possible option is to pre-draw the lines to an image and then just draw the image.

Comment: yes, but since the panel has a quite large min scroll value, changing an image of that size is even more resource expensive

Comment: Changing the image? Of course, you should only update the part where changes occurred. Which size are we talking about? And there shouldn't be many changes, right?

Comment: not many. couple of lines, (current resolution would be somewhere 3000,2000) problem is, once rendered into an image the previous lines I cannot get rig of easily. so if someone "Unplugs" the connection from one button to another, the connection representing lines should change appropriately, initially to go only till the mouse cursor, but cease to exist alltogether the moment I let the mouse go. I don't know how I would resolve this if I would use an image.

Comment: If it is hard to update, then just redraw from scratch. If it is just once (and not on every paint event), this should hardly be noticeable. You can draw the current line (that is being interacted with) directly to the panel and only if it is locked to the image.

Comment: ok. Will try that thanks.